# Adding references search folder for MSBuild from Visual Studio Build definition UI

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration

I am working on configuring a XAML build definition for a .net solution (of another company) stored in TFS2015.

The solution uses Dll references from a software X, installed on the developers computers, but not present in the Build server. (FTS and Build servers are shared among many clients).

I have option to add the required Dlls in a folder along with the source code, but I do not have option to modify the .csproj files.

In the Build definition, I tried to add the following in the MSBuild arguments field :

```
/p:AdditionalLibPaths=$/[long tfs path here]/CommonDlls

/p:AdditionalLibPaths=$(SourceDir)/CommonDlls
```

but it is not working.

Ideally, I would like to specify a relative folder from the root of the source code. 
(a static path might work but only for one build server and agent, which is not the objective of shared build).

Any ideas on how I can define this parameter ?

There is also option to add a prebuild script path. I can store a script file along with source code. Any pointers for how to write such script file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really need a script.
There are two things to make this work.

The first step is making sure that the DLLs are downloaded to the Agent working folder, the simplest way is have the `$/[long tfs path here]/CommonDlls` mapped in the Build Workspace; this is specified in the **Source Settings** tab of the Build Definition. Be careful to use the `$(SourceDir)` token in the mapping (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190721%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)).

The second point is to use a proper reference to the downloaded folder: use the `TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY` variable (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) for full list).

So, if you added a mapping like

`$/[long tfs path here]/CommonDlls` -> `$(SourceDir)\CommonDlls`

use `$(TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY)\CommonDlls`.

Comment: The answer helped pass the path parameter correctly.But "AdditionalLibPaths" did not achieve required result. Replacing it with ReferencePath worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It took me almost 20 trials to get the right one, it all started with how long it took that warning to consider all other directories, I could've ignored it but here's the warning first

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "nameOfDllFile". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

and this is the argument that got it working

```
/p:ReferencePath="$(build.sourcesdirectory)\Binaries"
```

where Binaries is the equivalent to CommonDlls from the question, and it is all because of the vague documentation and differences between versions of MSBuild, mine is 14.0 (VS2015).

Comment: Perfect. ReferencePath worked. It just killed me several hours. I wish i came across this much early in my search. Thanks a TON